# Conditional Formatting in Excel - 4 columns

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Okay, this is probably pretty simple but far beyond my normal duties in Excel.

I have four columns, with varying values in each row.  For example:

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
--+-----+-----+-----+-----+-
1 |  1  |  3  |  4  |  5  |
--+-----+-----+-----+-----+-
2 |  3  |  1  |  4  |  5  |
--+-----+-----+-----+-----+-
3 |  2  |  2  |  3  |  1  |
--+-----+-----+-----+-----+-
4 |  3  |  2  |  7  |  1  |
--+-----+-----+-----+-----+-
```

I would like to have the highest number in each row (5, 5, 3, 7 in the example) highlighted a certain color.  I'm having the most trouble figuring out how to adjust the formula to include the entire range of the document.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
=(A1=MAX($A1:$D1))
```

Using dollar signs in the range `$A1:$D1` will cause it to always cover the same columns (from A to D)

Comment: @brianasher: hi friend if the answer solves your problem, make the question answered.